# Hour of DST change in Oracle database seems to be 1 am instead of 2 am

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to convert from UTC time to BST time in Oracle - however, it seems the data change time in oracle is 1 am instead of 2 am. Or what am i missing here? I used following code to illustrate and test the problem:

```
WITH time1 AS (select cast('2020-03-29 01:00:00 UTC' ASTIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AS UTC_time FROM dual)
SELECT UTC_time, (UTC_time AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London') AS bst FROM time1
```

And at 1:00:00 UTC, the BST time is 2:00:00 - and it should be 1:00:00

Comment: Why do you think that is wrong? [GMT changes to BST at 2020-03-29 01:00:00](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london).

Comment: DST time takes effect at 2:00 am, not at 1

Comment: No it doesn't. For GMT/BST anyway. Other regions have different rules, and different local times; the GMT/BST change happens at the same UTC time as CET/CEST (by design I believe), so in Paris say the change is at 02:00 CET - which is still 01:00 UTC.

Comment: Try `TIMESTAMP '2020-03-29 01:00:00 UTC'` instead of the cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle is right, your expectation seems to be wrong. You can see the Europe/London DST changes [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london).

[The IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) has the following for Europe/London:

```
# See EU for rules starting in 1996.
...
# Zone  NAME            GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Europe/London   -0:01:15 -      LMT     1847 Dec  1  0:00s
                         0:00   GB-Eire %s      1968 Oct 27
                         1:00   -       BST     1971 Oct 31  2:00u
                         0:00   GB-Eire %s      1996
                         0:00   EU      GMT/BST
```

so since 1996 the UK has been following the EU rules, which are:

```
# Europe

# The following rules are for the European Union and for its
# predecessor organization, the European Communities.
# For brevity they are called "EU rules" elsewhere in this file.

# Rule  NAME    FROM    TO      TYPE    IN      ON      AT      SAVE    LETTER/S
Rule    EU      1977    1980    -       Apr     Sun>=1   1:00u  1:00    S
Rule    EU      1977    only    -       Sep     lastSun  1:00u  0       -
Rule    EU      1978    only    -       Oct      1       1:00u  0       -
Rule    EU      1979    1995    -       Sep     lastSun  1:00u  0       -
Rule    EU      1981    max     -       Mar     lastSun  1:00u  1:00    S
Rule    EU      1996    max     -       Oct     lastSun  1:00u  0       -
```

So... in the UK (and the rest of the EU) DST is applied from the last Sunday in March at 01:00 UTC, which next year is 2020-03-29 01:00:00 UTC. And it stays on DST until the last Sunday in October at 01:00 UTC, which next year is 2020-10-25 01:00:00 UTC.

Oracle is following those rules:

```
with time1 (utc_time) as (
            select timestamp '2020-03-29 00:00:00.000 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-03-29 00:59:59.999 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-03-29 01:00:00.000 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-03-29 01:59:59.999 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-03-29 02:00:00.000 UTC' FROM dual
  --
  union all select timestamp '2020-10-25 00:00:00.000 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-10-25 00:59:59.999 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-10-25 01:00:00.000 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-10-25 01:59:59.999 UTC' FROM dual
  union all select timestamp '2020-10-25 02:00:00.000 UTC' FROM dual
)
select utc_time,
  utc_time at time zone 'Europe/London' as london_time,
  to_char(utc_time at time zone 'Europe/London', 'TZD') as "DST?"
from time1
order by utc_time;

UTC_TIME                          LONDON_TIME                                 DST?  
--------------------------------- ------------------------------------------- ------
2020-03-29 00:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-03-29 00:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON GMT   
2020-03-29 00:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-03-29 00:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/LONDON GMT   
2020-03-29 01:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-03-29 02:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON BST   
2020-03-29 01:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-03-29 02:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/LONDON BST   
2020-03-29 02:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-03-29 03:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON BST   
2020-10-25 00:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-10-25 01:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON BST   
2020-10-25 00:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-10-25 01:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/LONDON BST   
2020-10-25 01:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-10-25 01:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON GMT   
2020-10-25 01:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-10-25 01:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/LONDON GMT   
2020-10-25 02:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-10-25 02:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON GMT
```

In central Europe DST applies from the same UTC time, but of course the local time is different:

```
with time1 (utc_time) as (
  ...
)
select utc_time,
  utc_time at time zone 'Europe/Paris' as paris_time,
  to_char(utc_time at time zone 'Europe/Paris', 'TZD') as "DST?"
from time1
order by utc_time;

UTC_TIME                          PARIS_TIME                                 DST?  
--------------------------------- ------------------------------------------ ------
2020-03-29 00:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-03-29 01:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS CET   
2020-03-29 00:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-03-29 01:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/PARIS CET   
2020-03-29 01:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-03-29 03:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS CEST  
2020-03-29 01:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-03-29 03:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/PARIS CEST  
2020-03-29 02:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-03-29 04:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS CEST  
2020-10-25 00:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-10-25 02:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS CEST  
2020-10-25 00:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-10-25 02:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/PARIS CEST  
2020-10-25 01:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-10-25 02:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS CET   
2020-10-25 01:59:59.999000000 UTC 2020-10-25 02:59:59.999000000 EUROPE/PARIS CET   
2020-10-25 02:00:00.000000000 UTC 2020-10-25 03:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS CET
```

*Possibly* that is why you were expecting to not see the time change until 02:00, but if so you're confusing UTC and local time, and/or UK and central Europe.

---

Not directly relevant to your question, but in my CTE I've switched from casting a string to a timsetamp, to using [a timestamp literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1). As well as being slightly less typing, the format is unambiguous. When you cast you're relying on the session's NLS settings matching the string format you've supplied, so although the cast works for you, it might not work for someone else running your code. If you don't want to (or can't) use literals then it's safer to use `to_timestamp_tz()` with an explicit format mask.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer :) I was indeed mistaken